# How to read .txt file with lines formatted like [[xxx],[yyy]] in order do access [xxx] and [yyy] directly?

Tags: python, for-loop, text, read-write

I have script that writes `.txt` file in such format, that is looks like this:

```
[[1.905568], ['Thu Sep 26 13:17:26 2019']]
[[3.011008], ['Thu Sep 26 13:17:27 2019']]
[[3.10576], ['Thu Sep 26 13:17:28 2019']]
[[2.94784], ['Thu Sep 26 13:17:29 2019']]
              etc.
```

Filling .txt file looks like this:

```
for x in range(len(List)):
        txtfile.write("{}\n".format(List[x])
```

in this script I can access value by `print(List[Row][0][0])` or date by `pirnt(List[Row][1][0])`

How should i construct for-loop in other script reading this .txt that I could access the data the same way like mentioned above?

Currently I'm reading line by line like: `List2 = txtfile.read().split('\n')`

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ast` for this purpose:

```
import ast

my_rows = []
with open("path_to_my.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        row = ast.literal_eval(line)
        my_rows.append(row)
```

You can now access your values with `my_rows[Row][0][0]` and dates with `my_rows[Row][1][0]` with `Row` corresponding to the row index.